# Is it possible to get a fixed image after every 6 items in list view?

Tags: android, image, listview

I want to place a image view after every 6 items.

Comment: Please post some relevant code, describing what effort you made and where exactly are you stuck

Comment: You should post some code then someone can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

in `getView()` method of base adapter try following logic:

```
if((position%6)==0)
{
imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourparticularimage)
}
else
{
//do other funtionality
}
```

Comment: after every 6 items how can i achive ...from example after 12th positon i want to get same image@satish Silveri

Comment: it all depends upon how to design you listview item

Answer (score 0):

Please go through callback of Adapter getItemViewType. You can load different views/layouts based on ITEM_TYPE. For your reference, 
[Android ListView with different layouts for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layouts-for-each-row)